# Dimension of an addition of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $A,B \subset V$ two subspaces of a finite dimension vector space $V$. I have to show that

$$\dim(A+B) = \dim(A) + \dim(B)$$

if $A \cap B = \{0\}$. How can I show this without just saying that 
$$\dim(A+B) = \dim(A) + \dim(B) - \dim(A \cap B)?$$ 
I have tried with example but I don't find one that work.

Comment: Use induction on the dimension.

Answer (score 5):

**Hints**. Let $(v_i \mid i = 1,\ldots, n)$ a basis of $A$ and $(v_i \mid i = n+1, \ldots, n+m)$ a basis of $B$. Show that $(v_i \mid i = 1, \ldots, n+m)$ is a basis of $A+B$ (you will need $A \cap B = 0$ in prooving that). The result follows.